# How change location of css tab

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm working with devtools and would like that my CSS tab is under the HTML elements.

So:
[image: 1]

Instead, I'm getting this:
[image: 2]

I know it may be very simple but haven't found the way to do it.

Comment: hi, did my answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

1. click on the gear icon.

[image: 1]

2. under Appearance -> panel layout you cab change to horizontal or vertical.

[image: 2]